# the header attribute set-Cookie is not set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I used the sanctum for authentication in my React JS and Laravel application. The issue is that while I successfully registered with the api in my React interface, the API that retrieves the user's information and moves them to the dashboard interface returns 401 unauthorized. When I checked the network, I discovered that header in the set-Cookie attribute and saw the message:

> "this attempt to set a cookie via set-cookie header was blocked because it had the "SameSite=Lax" attribute but came from a cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level navigation"

This is my code of login

```
  async function handleLogin() {
    try {
      const csrf = await api.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
      const login = await api.post("/api/v1/auth/login", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
  
      const user = await api.get("/api/v1/user");
  
      if (user.status >= 200 && user.status < 300) {
        navigate("/dashboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login failed:", error);
      navigate("/login")
    }
  }
```

and this is my form. I'm using nextui

```
 <CardBody className="flex flex-col gap-5 p-6">
            <Input
              isRequired
              type="email"
              label="Email"
              size="sm"
              isInvalid={isInvalid}
              color={isInvalid ? "danger" : ""}
              errorMessage={isInvalid && "Please enter a valid email"}
              onValueChange={setEmail}
            />
            <Input
              isRequired
              isInvalid={isPasswordInvalid}
              color={isPasswordInvalid ? "danger" : ""}
              errorMessage={
                isPasswordInvalid &&
                "The password should be 8 characters containing: \n uppercase, lowercase, special character and numbers"
              }
              onValueChange={setPassword}
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              size="sm" 
            />
            <Button color="primary" onClick={handleLogin}>
              Login
            </Button>
          </CardBody>
```

I have actually tried setting `sameSite` to none and add secure as I have seen in other solutions but it didn't work and as for API configuration. I set `withCredentials` to true and I'm working locally. I hope you can help.

Comment: If your API is on a different port than your front end the browser will not send cookies even if they’re on the same domain (e.g. localhost) iirc.

Comment: @ray can you explain further please? and help me identify the problem